# Binary search function in C

Tags: c, arrays, search, binary

The program 'randomly' chooses a set of 8 numbers and then the user has to guess as many of those numbers as they can. But even if I type in the numbers in this array of random numbers, the binary_search function doesn't find that exact number in the array of 'random' numbers. I can't seem to find the mistake in my binary_search function (at least I suspect that that's where the problem is). I have tried the program with large SIZE of numbers and small too. Could anyone help me please?

```
#define SIZE 3
#define min  1
#define max  36

int random();
bool binary_search(int value, int values[], int n);

int main(void)
{
    int numbers[SIZE];
    for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        numbers[i] = random();
    int score = 0;
    int n[SIZE];
    int number_user;


    for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {   
        //Type in a number
        do
        {
            printf("Search number no.%d:\n> ", i + 1);
            n[i] = GetInt();

            //Wrong input number
            if(n[i] < min || n[i] > max)
            {
                printf("\nNumber should be between %d - %d!!!\n\n", min , max);
            }
        }
        while(n[i] < min || n[i] > max);

        //THE PROBLEMATIC STUFF - START
        number_user = n[i];
        if (binary_search(number_user, numbers, SIZE))
        {
            printf("FOUND!!!\n");
            score += 1;
        }
        else 
        {
            printf("NOT IN THE LIST\n");
        }
        //PROBLEMATIC STUFF - FINISH
    }

    //scoring
    printf("\n\n*******SCORE*******\n");
        //print your numbers
        for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        {
            printf(" %d", n[i]);
            if(i != SIZE - 1)
                printf(",");
            if(i == SIZE - 1)
                printf(".\n");
        }

        //print right numbers
        printf("\nRight numbers are:");
        for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        {
            printf(" %d", numbers[i]);
            if(i != SIZE - 1)
                printf(",");
            if(i == SIZE - 1)
                printf(".\n");
        }

    int result = score / SIZE * 100;
    printf("Your score is: %d / %d , %d %%\n", score, SIZE, result);


    return 0;    
}
 //PROBLEM START
bool binary_search(int value, int values[], int n)
{
    int beginning = 0;
    int ending = n - 1;

    int middle;

    while (ending >= beginning) 
    {    
        middle = (beginning + ending) / 2; 
        for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        {
            //look at middle of list if (binary_search(n, numbers, SIZE))
            if(values[middle] == value)
                //if number found, return true 
                return true;

            //else if middle higher, search left 
            else if(values[middle] > value)
                ending = middle - 1;

            //else if middle lower, search right 
            else if(values[middle] < value)
                beginning = middle + 1;
        } 
    }
    return false; 
}
//PROBLEM FINISH

int random()
{
    int r = rand() % ((max - min + 1) + min);

    return r;
}
```

Comment: What's the point of the `for` loop in your binary search?

Comment: I think it is necessary to sort up to before to search for numbers.

Comment: No, it really isn't...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Binary search is about sorted array / list / etc ... and your program feels randomal numbers.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm (the second line).

Answer (score 2):

Inside your binary search function you have this loop...

```
for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
{
    ...
}
```

Inside it, you change the `beginning` and `ending` values many times without changing `middle`. This means `beginning` and `ending` are adjusted several times based on a single value of `middle`, which in turn means it can "disqualify" ranges of the array that would actually have the number you're searching for.

Furthermore, as **MeNa** points out in his/her answer, binary search is meant for searching ordered data sets. It's useless for arrays in random order.

Answer (score 1):

If that isn't homework you can try using [`bsearch`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/functions/bsearch.html) if you have it. (It's a POSIX function.)